# How do I mutate/modify an instance attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, instance, mutation

I want to distinguish the first time I initiate a class from all the other times I initiate it. I've created an instance attribute and set its value to True. What do I do for all subsequent instances to have that attribute value as False?

```
class Cool(Dude): 

    def __init__(self):
        self.coolnesscheck = True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class attribute, to indicate if the first object has been created or not. Example -

```
class Cool:
    __firstinit = True

    def __init__(self):
        self.coolnesscheck = Cool.__firstinit
        Cool.__firstinit = False
```

I am prepending `__` in the name to introduce [*Name Mangling*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) , so that the attribute is not easily accessible outside the class.

Comment: Just by the way here, but the `if..else` is unnecessary - it matches the antipattern of `if x == 1: return 1; elif x == 2: return 2...`.

Comment: If you replace `Cool` by `self.__class__` in the class methods (here `__init__`), you can then rename the class as you like without altering the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class attribute, and set it to `False` when you instantiate an object of that class:

```
>>> class Cool:
...     coolnesscheck = True
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.coolnesscheck = Cool.coolnesscheck
...         Cool.coolnesscheck = False
...
>>> Cool.coolnesscheck
True
>>> a = Cool()
>>> Cool.coolnesscheck
False
>>> a.coolnesscheck
True
>>> b = Cool()
>>> Cool.coolnesscheck
False
>>> b.coolnesscheck
False
```